# WSO2 - iteration through xml response

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I manged to do similar with JSON response but now I'm stuck.
I have a data service that returns XML. I created end point and now I want to go over response and call another endpoint to write custom MQ message.

result from Dataservice is like

```
<VINS xmlns="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">
<VIN>
<TransactionDate>2017-03-01-06:00</TransactionDate>
<VIN>5TDXZ3XXXXXX</VIN>
<DealerCode>YYYY</DealerCode>
</VIN>
```

and my API looks like :

```
<resource methods="GET" uri-template="/{dlrcode}">
<inSequence>
<log level="custom">
<property expression="fn:concat(' DLR code ',get-property('uri.var.dlrcode'))" name="Allocation GET api  method is called for"/>
</log>
<property description="DLR Code" expression="get-property('uri.var.dlrcode')" name="dlrCode" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
<call>
<endpoint key="getAllocationVehicles"/>
</call>
<log level="custom">
<property name="call status " value="ok"/>
</log>
<iterate continueParent="true" expression="//VINS" id="MyIterator" xmlns:ns="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice" sequential="true">
<target>
<sequence>
<log level="custom">
<property name="iteration " value="working..."/>
</log>
<property description="VIN" expression="//VINS/VIN" name="vin" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
<property description="TransactionDate" expression="//VINS/DealerCode" name="trsDate" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
<property name="FORCE_SC_ACCEPTED" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="true"/>
<property action="remove" name="TRANSPORT_HEADERS" scope="axis2"/>
<property name="OUT_ONLY" scope="default" type="STRING" value="true"/>
<payloadFactory description="VIN message" media-type="json">
<format>{"DLRCode":"$1","VIN":"$2","TrDate":"$3"}</format>
<args>
<arg evaluator="xml" expression="$ctx:dlrCode"/>
<arg evaluator="xml" expression="$ctx:vin"/>
<arg evaluator="xml" expression="$ctx:trsDate"/>
</args>
</payloadFactory>
<call>
<endpoint>
<address uri="jms:/LocalQueue2?transport.jms.Destination=LocalQueue2">
<timeout>
<duration>5</duration>
<responseAction>fault</responseAction>
</timeout>
</address>
</endpoint>
</call>
</sequence>
</target>
</iterate>
<respond/>
</inSequence>
<outSequence>
<log level="full"/>
</outSequence>
<faultSequence/>
</resource>
```

in log I see that call to Data service is done because I'm getting

**Allocation GET api method is called for = DLR code ABC**

and

**call status = ok**

BUT it looks that I'm not getting into iteration because there is no message

**iteration = working...**

Im guesting thet my issue is on iteration declaration but i don't see it ..

thanks to Jeam-Michel I want to put correct iteration for clarity

---

```
<iterate continueParent="true" expression="//ns:VINS/ns:VIN" id="MyIterator" sequential="true" xmlns:ns="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">
                <target>
                    <sequence>
                        <property description="VIN" expression="//ns:VIN/text()" name="vin" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
                        <property description="TransactionDate" expression="//ns:TransactionDate/text()" name="trsDate" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
                        <property description="Dlr code for Veh" expression="//ns:DealerCode/text()" name="trsDLR" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
                        <property name="FORCE_SC_ACCEPTED" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="true"/>
                        <property action="remove" name="TRANSPORT_HEADERS" scope="axis2"/>
                        <property name="OUT_ONLY" scope="default" type="STRING" value="true"/>
                        <payloadFactory description="VIN message" media-type="json">
                            <format>{"DLRCode":"$1","VIN":"$2","TrDate":"$3"}</format>
                            <args>
                                <arg evaluator="xml" expression="$ctx:trsDLR"/>
                                <arg evaluator="xml" expression="$ctx:vin"/>
                                <arg evaluator="xml" expression="$ctx:trsDate"/>
                            </args>
                        </payloadFactory>
                        <call>
                            <endpoint>
                                <address uri="jms:/LocalQueue2?transport.jms.Destination=LocalQueue2">
                                    <timeout>
                                        <duration>5</duration>
                                        <responseAction>fault</responseAction>
                                    </timeout>
                                </address>
                            </endpoint>
                        </call>
                    </sequence>
                </target>
            </iterate>
```

It works like a charm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All the nodes in your result belongs to namespace `http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice`

You've just defined this namespace in your iterate, but you need to specify it inside the xpath :

```
<iterate continueParent="true" expression="//ds:VINS" id="MyIterator" xmlns:ds="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice" sequential="true">
```